# Change css value from admin panel with php

Tags: php, mysql, css

I need to change values in a stylesheet from an admin panel using php. I know I can do this inserting the values to my MySql database but isn't there a better way?

So far I have converted my style.css to style.php and it looks like this:

```
  <?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    $pageBG = '#ff0';
  ?>
```

What I want to do is to change the hex value (`#ff0`) from my admin panel with a color picker.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking too much.

- A color picker needs at least javascript
- An admin control panel needs at least a database + an auth plataform

You should open another question with more specific stuff.

If you want the easiest way you can just edit your style.css file and make your changes by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use color picker it's a frontend issue not related to having it configurable at all. If you want to make admin panel's or site's look customizable, there's no other way than storing some settings in database. You may utilize INI files, but's that only other container. One tip: Generate CSS file and don't regenerate it until you tell you script to. If you save new settings - regenerate it, other way use the already existent one.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot change css**, though you **can dynamically generate** it.
Supposing you are using apache you can have .css files go through php before being served. thus you could have something like

```
.dynamicColor
{
  color: <?= $color ?>;
} /* $color must be exctracted from mysql */
```

more general solution would be to create a php script createCSS, which would load variables from mysql and include prebuilt css script (like in previous example) and set content-type header to text/css